# Постоянное обновление textBox`а

Tags: c++-cli

Я запрашиваю строку с текстом, которую вывожу в textBox

```
char* log;
if (getLogMess(log)) logTextBox->Text += gcnew String(log) + "\n";
```

Что мне нужно сделать дальше:

1. Сделать автоматический запрос новой строки
2. Добавить возможность отключения и включения авто запросов.

Я хотел всё реализовать в отдельном потоке с бесконечным циклом, но в CLI нельзя изменять формы в отдельном потоке

```
void MyForm::updateLog() {
    char* log;
    while (true) {
        if (getLogMess(log)) logTextBox->Text += gcnew String(log) + "\n";
    }
}
Thread^ updateLogThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::updateLog));
updateLogThread->Start();
```

Как быть?

**UPD**

Рабочий вариант:

```
delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate();
Thread^ updateLogThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::updateLog));
updateLogThread->Start();

char* log;
void MyForm::updateLog() {

    while (true) {
        if (this->logTextBox->InvokeRequired) {
            StringArgReturningVoidDelegate^ d =
                gcnew StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(this, &MyForm::updateLog);
            this->Invoke(d);
        } else {
            if (!getLogMess(log)) return;
            this->logTextBox->Text += gcnew String(log) + "\r\n";
        }
        Threading::Thread::Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Осуществление потокобезопасных вызовов элементов управления Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke позволит вам изменить форму из любого потока. Вот пример его использования в моём проекте.

```
listBox_COM.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox_COM.Items.Add(data)));
```

Comment: Прекрасно, спасибо! Я написал как `logTextBox->Invoke(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::updateLog));`

Comment: @Виталий - по-моему, вы неправильно написали. `Invoke` должен вызываться в другом (не-gui) потоке. А у вас новый поток создаётся в `Invoke`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ага, несколько накосячил. Сейчас переделываю